# react-native: flatlist with dynamic numColumns depending json params

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

This is my json:

```
{
   data:[
      {id:1,type:0...},{id:2,type:0...},{id:3,type:1...},
   ]
}
```

and Flatlist

```
_keyExtractor = (item,index) => item.id.toString();

<FlatList
   data={this.state.products}
   renderItem={this.renderItem}
   keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
   numColumns={3}
/>
```

I want something like this:

```
 numColumns={item.type ? 1 : 2}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `numColumns` sets the number of columns for the global FlatList, but it is possible to create a similar behavior in your `renderItem` function.

Of course it is possible that you have to modify the structure of your data beforehand, so that this workaround is applicable for you.

See example below:

**Data:**

```
  this.state={
            data:[
      {id:1,type:0},{id:2,type:1},{id:3,type:1},
      {id:4,type:0},{id:5,type:1},{id:6,type:0},
   ]
        }
```

Render:

```
const WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width; // get the screen width 

renderItem({item}){
    // if type == 0, render two views side by side
    if (item.type == 0){
        return(
            <View style={{width: WIDTH, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', width: WIDTH/2 }}>
                    <Text> {item.id} a) </Text>
                </View>
                <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'blue', width: WIDTH/2 }}>
                    <Text> {item.id} b) </Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }else{
        // otherwise render only one item 
        return (
            <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'green', width: WIDTH }}>
                <Text> {item.id} </Text>
            </View>
        );
    } 
}
render() {
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList
            data={this.state.data}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
            renderItem={(item) => this.renderItem(item)}
            />
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}
```

**Image:**

[image: Image example]